# Error cannot read property of undefined when trying to test a component that uses redux

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a class based Dashboard component

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
 ...
 render() {
   return sth
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userId: state.mainState.userId,
  theme: state.mainState.theme,
  companyUsers: state.mainState.companyUsers,
  activities: state.mainState.activities,
  activityTypes: state.mainState.activityTypes,
  projects: state.mainState.projects
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setMainValue: actions.setMainValue
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Dashboard));
```

Now I am trying to start testing the component using jest and react-testing-library.
I have created a renderWithProvider function similar to this [article](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests) and trying to test using the custom render function. The only difference is that in the official redux website it returns the whole state on mapStateToProps as it is short while I am returning only specific variables.

```
function renderWithProvider(ui, { initialState, ...renderOptions } = {}) {
 const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }

  Wrapper.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };

  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { renderWithProvider };
```

When I render the component and run the test

```
import Dashboard from '.';

import { renderWithProvider } from '../testUtils/renderWithProvider'

test('should ', () => {
  renderWithProvider(<Dashboard />, {
    initialState: {
      userId: 106,
      theme: 'light',
      companyUsers: [],
      activities: [],
      activityTypes: [],
      projects: []
    }
  });
});
```

I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
>
> ```
>   334 |
>   335 | const mapStateToProps = state => ({
>   336 |   userId: state.mainState.userId,
> ```

Any suggestions are welcome

**Edit**: I have tried also the following:

```
test('should ', () => {
  renderWithProvider(<Dashboard />, {
    initialState: {
      mainState: {
        userId: 106,
        theme: 'light',
        companyUsers: [],
        activities: [],
        activityTypes: [],
        projects: []
      }
    }
  });
});
```

but keep getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot I found that the issue eventually was related with the use of `history` library and the use of `rootReducer(history)` on project's store.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer(history),
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunk))
);
```

Once I passed `rootReducer` as a function and history as an argument on rootReducer similarly to store initialization `store.getState()`  inside  `renderWithProvider` was no longer `undedined`, therefore mainState also and its values:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

function renderWithProvider(ui, { initialState, ...renderOptions } = {}) {
 const store = createStore(rootReducer(history), initialState, 
 applyMiddleware(thunk));
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initialValue is wrong based on the expected structure in your mapStateToProps.  These properties that you are passing need to be sub-properties of a mainState property rather than top-level properties of the root state.

Comment: How it should be passed then? I have tried also passing `initialState: {mainState: ... } }` but keep getting the same error. Could you include an example?

Comment: Hmm initialState: {mainState: { userId: 106, ... } } should be correct.  I can look at this more later — I’m on my phone.

Comment: ok. thank you. I 'll be waiting. A thing to mention is that this component is displayed as a result of routing and I have not included this on my custom render function yet. Could it be a problem at this point?

Comment: I don’t think so because the error is definitely that state.mainState is undefined inside mapStateToProps.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Dumb question but is your reducer missing a default case?  That would cause the initial state to be ignored.  But I’m assuming that the component works and this is just a testing issue.

Comment: No it doesn't. it has a default case and everything works as expected when running the App. The problem occurs when running the test and it happens in other components as well similar to Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution. It was related with something different. +1